# Error when creation PLR extension Postgres

Tags: sql, r, postgresql, plr

I'm trying to create PLR extension in Postgres 10.4 and it gives me error:

```
ERROR:  could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/10/lib/plr.dll": The specified module could not be found.


SQL state: XX000
```

I use Windows 10, R 3.4.2. I downloaded PL/R of this version:  Win64 plr.dll for Postgres 10.x, R-3.4.2 (plr-8.3.0.17)

I put dll file in the lib folder as required and restarted the psql service. `R_HOME` is set to C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2.

Path variables: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\lib and  C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need also plr.control and corresponding sql files in `share/extension/` folder.

[Newer version of PL/R](https://github.com/postgres-plr/plr/releases) does not require `R_HOME` anymore on Windows as long as the proper information is in the Windows Registry `HKLM\SOFTWARE\R-core\R`. Uninstalling older versions of R may remove that!!!